# Converting a C++ GUID structure to NSString* in Objective-C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, xamarin.ios, objective-c++

I am trying to implement the following method in Objective-C:

```
- (NSString*) getGuidWithCid: (int) cid;
```

This method must retrieve a GUID from a database using a C++ API and then convert this GUID into a string representation of the GUID. The structure *GUID* returned by the C++ API has the following definition:

```
typedef struct _GUID {
    ul_u_long   Data1;
    ul_u_short  Data2;
    ul_u_short  Data3;
    ul_byte     Data4[ 8 ];
} GUID;
```

Here is my attempt to implement this method:

```
- (NSString*) getGuidWithCid: (int) cid
{
    GUID ulguid;
    ((ULResultSet *) ulresultset)->GetGuid([cname UTF8String], &ulguid);
    NSString* data4 = [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:ulguid.Data4
                                         length:8
                                         encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u-%uh-%uh-%@", 
                     ulguid.Data1, 
                     ulguid.Data2,
                     ulguid.Data3, 
                     data4];
}
```

The first two lines of this method are working fine, so the variable *ulguid* contains a valid guid. The problem I am having is with the conversion of the byte array portion of the GUID (ie. Data4 in the GUID structure). What I am getting back from this method currently is three numeric values separated by hyphens, so Data1, Data2 and Data3 seem to be represented correctly, but NULL is being shown for Data4. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

You are calling `release` on `data4` immedaitely after you create it. The contents of the string, therefore, are invalid at the point you try to use it. Consider calling `autorelease` instead.

Comment: Thanks, fbrereto. I have corrected that, but I am still getting null returned.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the bytes in ulguid.Data4 don't form a valid UTF8 string, so you get nil back when you try to create a string with those bytes.

Comment: I think you are on the right track here, Caleb. I think what I am struggling with is what the byte array portion of the GUID actually contains. I thought I could just convert it to a UTF8 string, but clearly there is more to it than that. I have found the following link which explains the GUID structure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373931%28VS.85%29.aspx. It seems I need to read the first 2 bytes separately from the last 6 bytes. I'm not quite sure at this stage how I am to do that.

Comment: Get rid of string `data4` and change the format string to use %qX, which prints an 8-byte int as hex. Then pass in `ulguid.Data4` as the 4th value rather than `data4`. Also, shouldn't the entire string be in hexadecimal format? If so, then the format string should be something like: @"%X-%uX-%uX-%qX", though I see now that you've found an equivalent solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully implemented this method as follows:

```
- (NSString*) getGuidWithCid: (int) cid
{
    GUID ulguid;
    ((ULResultSet *) ulresultset)->GetGuid(cid, &ulguid);

    char buffer[37];

    sprintf(buffer, "%08X-%04X-%04X-%02X%02X-%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",
                    ulguid.Data1, ulguid.Data2, ulguid.Data3,
                    ulguid.Data4[0], ulguid.Data4[1],
                    ulguid.Data4[2], ulguid.Data4[3],
                    ulguid.Data4[4], ulguid.Data4[5],
                    ulguid.Data4[6], ulguid.Data4[7]);

    return [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer 
                              length:sizeof(buffer) 
                              encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
}
```

Thanks goes to Ferdinand Beyer (http://stackoverflow.com/users/34855/ferdinand-beyer) for helping me get to this solution.